# Hyperledger composer integration with Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have 3 physical machines namely node1,node2 and node3.

> ```
> node 1 is orderer
> node 2 and node 3 are the peers
> ```

I was able to to deploy chain code and retrieve back the result. Now I am trying to use Hyper ledger composer and deploy chain code.

I have installed composer play-ground locally in node1 (orderer). Started Orderer and 2 peers.

1. Is it possible to deploy chain code in node1 written in composer-playground. Could you explain how to set up or point me to right document.
2. How to set up connection profile in composer-playground?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these instructions:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html

That will create and start a Fabric for you and configure the security such that Composer can deploy.